# How do you transfer an existing timeline to the home page without showing the tasks?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, timeline

I'm new to SharePoint and I want to make a change to my team's timeline. Essentially, there are three existing timelines on three different pages. I want to take all of those timelines and put them on the homepage as one timeline or as separate timelines (without the tasks) if possible. Would anybody know a noncode or code version of doing this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add just a timeline web part where the tasks will not show up.  To do so add a web part on your page under `Content Rollup` -> `Timeline`.  After the web part is on the page you can configure the settings to display which list you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know if you can have a single timeline display tasks from multiple task lists, or is that not possible?